# Почему регулярное выражение срабатывает в тестере, но не работает в Gmail?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, gmail

Мне на почту поступают заявки в формате

> %Имя% оставил заявку, его телефон %номер% Почта этого пользователя: %почта%
> Вакансия: %название%
> Дополнительная информация: %инфо%

Часть заявок пустые, и я хотел отфильтровать заполненные, с помощью регулярного выражения.
Пошёл по самому простому пути и выбрал выражение, которое показывало только письма, у которых перед "оставил" есть пробел и какие-либо символы: \D+\s(оставил). Выражение работает в тестировщике, однако в интерфейсе gmail результатов не выдаёт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=ru возможно регулярные выражения попросту не поддерживаются поисковиком писем.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346938?hl=ru
поддерживаются, в том-то и дело, указано, что используется синтаксис RE2

Comment: Это для администраторов, а не настройки поиска или фильтров, перейдите на страницу https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934 и разверните спойлер *Откройте настройки соответствия Gmail в консоли администратора Google*, если там будет `Используйте аккаунт администратора (ваш текущий аккаунт xxxxxx@gmail.com не подходит)` то значит таких прав на вашей уз нет